# How can I make a big Python package modular?

Tags: python-3.x

In my company, we have a Python project that contains a hierarchy of lots of packages and modules shared by our different applications. But what seemed a good idea to mutualise code has become something horribly difficult to use and maintain.

Depending on the end-project, we use a single module from this library, or a single package, or many. And some modules/packages are independent, but some others depend on other packages and modules from the same library. And of course those modules depend on third-party packages.

I would like to make it as modular as possible, i.e. I would like to deal with the following cases:

- use the whole library
- use a single package from that library (whether it is a top level package or not)
- use a single module from the library
- use multiple packages/modules from the library (possibly interdependent)

Moreover, a strong constraint I have is not to break existing code so that I can make the project transformation without breaking all the projects of my coworkers...

---

Here is an example file tree that represents the situation:

```
library
├── a
│   └── i
│       ├── alpha.py         # each module may depend on any other package / module
│       └── beta.py
├── b
│   ├── delta.py
│   ├── gamma.py
│   └── j
│       └── epsilon.py
├── c
│   ├── mu.py
│   └── nu.py
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

The best solution I found is to add a `setup.py` and a `requirements.txt` in every folder of the tree. But this has serious limitations:

- I cannot use a single module (I have to use a package).
- When I use a package, I have to change its import statements. For example if, before any change, I use `from library.a.i import alpha`, I would like not to modify it afterwards.

Moreover, I am quite sure I am forgetting some of the constraints I have...

So is what I am trying to achieve feasible, or is it utopian?

Comment: Similar question have been asked many a times, please search again.

Comment: @AjayA I have already searched and never found anything. But honestly I do not really know what/where to search. Any pointer to give please?

Comment: Are you aware of namespace packages? You could have ``library.a``, ``library.b``, ``library.c`` and so on as separate packages, which all provide parts of ``library``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I did not know namespace packages. I will read to understand how to use it, and if it can solve my problem. Could you tell me if it fulfill with the constraint of being able and import a single module?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:
You need to have `PYTHONPATH` pointing on `library` or append it to `sys.path`
eg `sys.path.insert(0, 'path_to_libray')`

If you create `__init__.py` at each level of your folders you will be able to pick whatever level/module of interest eg:

in folder `b` :

```
from .delta import *
from .gamma import *
from b.j import *
```

in folder `j`:

```
from .epsilon import *
```

You can now do in any python script:

- `from b import *` : will import all of b contained modules
- `from b.j import *`: will import only epsilon stuff

Comment: Thx. But in my end project, I currently have `from library.b import delta`; when installing only *b* in my setup process, I will have to change these imports by `from b import delta`. In fact my problem is not *inside* the project, but in its interactions with other projects.

Comment: In any case refactory activities require to modify some existing code/modules/calls, I do not think there is a silver bullet here. Why can't you install only the required libraries keeping the original folder hierarchy 'including the top `library` one ? It is quite easy to list all 'owned' module imported by one of your projects using a part of the library folder.

Comment: I can make all the changes I want. But I know the more modifications there are, the more likely my colleagues may not want to make them...

Comment: What it you constraint for not installing b in a library folder? This way you would not have to change any import statement whether you run from within your development environnement or from a "deployment" location.